# SelectedItem dependency property never updates from UserControl

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have a `UserControl` that contains a `ListBox`, and I'm trying to enable external binding to various parts (`ItemsSource`, `SelectedItem`, `ItemTemplate`) of the `ListBox`. My understanding is Dependency Properties are the best way to accomplish this:

```
Public Class CellComboBoxControl

Public Shared ReadOnly ItemsSourceProperty As DependencyProperty = _
          DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", GetType(IEnumerable), GetType(CellComboBoxControl),
                                      New UIPropertyMetadata(Nothing))

Public Shared ReadOnly SelectedItemProperty As DependencyProperty = _
         DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", GetType(Object), GetType(CellComboBoxControl),
                                     New UIPropertyMetadata(Nothing))

Public Shared ReadOnly ItemTemplateProperty As DependencyProperty = _
     DependencyProperty.Register("ItemTemplate", GetType(DataTemplate), GetType(CellComboBoxControl),
                                 New UIPropertyMetadata(Nothing))

Sub New()

    InitializeComponent()

    Me.cb_ListBox.SetBinding(ListBox.SelectedItemProperty, New Binding("SelectedItem") With {.Source = Me, .Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay})

    Me.cb_ListBox.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemTemplateProperty, New Binding("ItemTemplate") With {.Source = Me, .Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay})

    Me.cb_ListBox.DataContext = Me

End Sub

Public Property ItemsSource As IEnumerable
    Get
        Return CType(GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty), IEnumerable)
    End Get
    Set(value As IEnumerable)
        SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Property SelectedItem As Object
    Get
        Return CType(GetValue(SelectedItemProperty), Object)
    End Get
    Set(value As Object)
        SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ItemTemplate As DataTemplate
    Get
        Return CType(GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty), DataTemplate)
    End Get
    Set(value As DataTemplate)
        SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property
```

The `ItemTemplate` and `ItemsSource` DPs work fine. However, when I add the `UserControl` to a `Window` like so:

```
<local:CellComboBoxControl Grid.Column="1" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding VolDefs}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding VolDef}">
```

`SelectedItem` does not behave as intended. Here I want the `SelectedItem` of the `ListBox` to update the source property `VolDef` when the user clicks on a listbox item. This does not appear to be happening.

So the data flow of the `ItemTemplate` and `ItemSource` bindings are "source-to-control" and they work fine, but `SelectedItem` binding needs to be "control-to-source" and it doesn't. Is this a limitation of Dependency Properties? Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

try updating you Itemsource Dependency Property to include this:

```
new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault))
```

The importance is the two way binding.